# How to get the list of divisors of a given number?

Tags: python

So the function inputs a list, and a number. Then it should return the index of the list that the number is able to be divided by. If there is no numbers in the list it can be divided by, then it should just return a blank list.

For example,

```
div([5,10,15,2,34],10)
[0,1,3]
```

Here is my coding:

```
def div(nlst, n):
    nlst = []
    for div in nlst:
        if n % nlst == 0:
        return nlst.index(div)
        else: []
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What is it about the coding I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues in your code:

```
def div(nlst, n):
    nlst = [] # You are deleting the original list here!
    for div in nlst: # The list nlst is empty
        if n % nlst == 0: # Cannot use a list 'nlst' as an operand of the % operation.
        return nlst.index(div) # You are returning a single element here
        else: [] # This does nothing
```

This code will do the job:

```
def div(nlst, n):
    result = []
    for i, e in enumerate(nlst):
        if n % e == 0:
            result.append(i)
    return result
```

A more compact version:

```
def div(nlst, n):
    return [i for i, e in enumerate(nlst) if n % e == 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions to the rescue:

```
def div(nlst, n):
    return [i for i,v in enumerate(nlst) if n % v == 0]

>>> div([5,10,15,2,34], 10)   
[0, 1, 3]
```